# Error usando mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

¿Podrían ayudarme con este pequeño código?

```
    <?php
    include("../app/database.php");
    if (isset($_POST['registrar'])){
        if (($_POST['nombre']!='') && ($_POST['email']!='') && ($_POST['clave']!='') && ($_POST['rclave']!='')){
            if ($_POST['clave'] != $_POST['rclave']){
                echo "Las contraseñas no coinciden.";
            }else{
                $name = proteger($_POST['nombre']);
                $mail = proteger($_POST['email']);
                $pass = md5(proteger($_POST['nombre']));
                $u_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                //VERIFICACION DE EXISTENCIA
                $q = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$mail");
                if(mysql_num_rows($q)>0){
                  echo "Dirección de Correo ya en uso.";
                }else{
                    $registrado = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,email,clave,ip) VALUES ('$name','$mail','$pass','$u_ip')");
                    echo "registrado con éxito!";
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

me genera el siguiente error:

```
 Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\page\registro.php on line 14
registrado con éxito!
```

Pero necesito que me diga que la dirección de correo ya esta en uso..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en la query. Falta una ' despues de la variable $email por lo que al hacer la query da error y la funcion mysql_query devuelve false en vez del recurso requerido y al hacer el mysql_num_rows sobre un booleano devuelve ese warning.

Cambia

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$mail");
```

por

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$mail'");
```

[Enlace al manual de php de la funcion mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) donde explica los valores de retorno.

Comment: Jajaja si tienes razón, errores técnicos, Gracias!

Comment: De nada. Me alegro que te haya funcionado :)

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @Lithorell es correcta aunque hay otro problema con tu script y es que estas usando el campo nombre en lugar de clave para guardar el MD5 de la contraseña.

cambia

```
$pass = md5(proteger($_POST['nombre']));
```

Por

```
$pass = md5(proteger($_POST['clave']));
```

Comment: Esto podría ser un comentario no?

Comment: Si es verdad, realmente no me había percatado de ese detalle bastante importante ademas, gracias!